# How can I make my program return to the original loop after calling exec?

Tags: c, linux, bash, shell

I have a program that is similar to a basic bash shell. I can run programs in the `/bin` directory from the shell. I have a builtin command checkEnv that uses a pager to display system variables exactly like `printenv | sort | less` but when `less` has completed, the program exits. I want to program to return to the shell. Can you tell my how I can do it? The way I create the pipeline is

```
cmd[0].argv= printenv;
cmd[1].argv= sort;
cmd[2].argv= pager_cmd;
fork_pipes(3, cmd);
```

where `cmd` is declared:

```
struct command
{
    char * const *argv;
};
struct command cmd[3];
```

I have helper functions to fork:

```
/* Helper function that forks pipes */
static void fork_pipes(int n, struct command *cmd)
{
    int i;
    int in = 0;
    int fd[2];
    int take_return;
    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i)
    {
        take_return = pipe(fd);
        ++take_return; /* Please the -O4 switch to gcc */
        spawn_proc(in, fd[1], cmd + i);
        close(fd[1]);
        in = fd[0];
    }
    if (dup2(in, 0) < 0)    {
        err_syserr("dup2() failed on stdin for %s: ", cmd[i].argv[0]);
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "%d: executing %s\n", (int)getpid(), cmd[i].argv[0]);
    execvp(cmd[i].argv[0], cmd[i].argv);
    err_syserr("failed to execute %s: ", cmd[i].argv[0]);
}

/* Helper function that spawns processes */
static int spawn_proc(int in, int out, struct command *cmd)
{
    pid_t pid;
    if ((pid = fork()) == 0)
    {
        if (in != 0)
        {
            if (dup2(in, 0) < 0)
                err_syserr("dup2() failed on stdin for %s: ", cmd->argv[0]);
            close(in);
        }
        if (out != 1)
        {
            if (dup2(out, 1) < 0)
                err_syserr("dup2() failed on stdout for %s: ", cmd->argv[0]);
            close(out);
        }
        fprintf(stderr, "%d: executing %s\n", (int)getpid(), cmd->argv[0]);
        execvp(cmd->argv[0], cmd->argv);
        err_syserr("failed to execute %s: ", cmd->argv[0]);
    }
    else if (pid < 0)   {
        err_syserr("fork failed: ");
    }
    return pid;
}
```

My problem is that the program exits when using the builtin command `checkEnv`. I want the program to return to the main loop that is the command prompt for my shell:

```
 while(1) {

        printf("miniShell>> ");
        memset(line, 0, sizeof line); /*Reset*/
        if(!fgets(line, BUFFER_LEN, stdin)) {
            break;
        }
```

Can you help me?

Comment: I do not see use of fork() or wait() system calls.

Comment: did you copy it from [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/85936/8481)? If so, did you read the comments?

Comment: @RTLinuxSW I added code that (I think) uses fork. Should we use wait() to enable to return to the shell?

Comment: @Wimmel yes, I built on that code. I updated the question with more code. I'm writing a program with basic shell functionality as an exercise to learn C and maybe we can make it work with some other system than linux eventually, but that is another question. Now I think that I must study how to use wait()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you forgot to call `fork` for the third process. You use just `exec` for it which means your main process (the miniShell) is substituted by pager_cmd. You should write something like that:

```
static void fork_pipes(int n, struct command *cmd)
{
    ... //calling spawn_proc two times
    pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0) { //child process (pager_cmd)
        execvp(cmd[i].argv[0], cmd[i].argv);
        err_syserr("failed to execute %s: ", cmd[i].argv[0]);
    } else if(pid > 0) {
        //call wait() for three pids we obtained by forking
    } else {
        //error handling
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like a good idea but if I do it then my program enters an infinite loop. Can you please elaborate how it should be done?

Comment: @Montao I haven't code of your entire program so I can't say where your program stucks in an infinite loop. Finding it out using a debugger is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you use exec (or any exec function type) every line defined under exec will not be executed because exec is like executing another program inside this program.